# How can I created filtered rows in SFMC to get data from past week?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, filters

I'm looking to filter my DE on the basis of data added.
For instance, today is 9 September. I want to filter all data that was added from 1 September to 8 September (i.e., last week), what are the data criteria I should be putting?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use following filter, to get records added within the last week:
[image]

However your example:

> today is 9 September. I want to filter all data that was added from 1
> September to 8 September

is not last week, but last full 7 days.
In this case, you would need to use:
[image]

Keep in mind, that timezone of Marketing Cloud is in CST and the server time does not change with standard versus daylight savings time. But these filters are running on the account time zone. So depending on what system populates Date Added field, you might need to observe the time zone offset.